# Incorrect file content after multipart upload

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, filepicker.io

I am trying to upload file to S3 using Filepicker API and request.js module.

```
content = "ABCDEF"
options =
  url: 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3'
  preambleCRLF: true # tried also with false
  postambleCRLF: true # tried also with false
  qs:
    key: 'XXX'
    store: 'S3'
    mimetype: 'text/csv'
    path: 'some-path.csv'
    container: 'my-bucket'
    access: 'public'
    multipart: [
      {
        body: content
      }
    ]
    method: 'post'

request options, (err, res, body) ->
  # 200 OK
```

It generally works however uploaded file content looks like this:

```
--6f63ec28-40de-425c-86d5-36f0befcec4a
ABCDEF
--6f63ec28-40de-425c-86d5-36f0befcec4a--
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this request was you have put multipart option inside querystring parameter. The request that worked for me was:

```
request = require("request");
  content = "ABCDEF";
  options = {
    url: 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3',
    preambleCRLF: true,
    postambleCRLF: true,
    multipart: [
        {
          body: content
        }
      ],
    method: 'post',
    qs: {
      key: 'APIKEY',
      store: 'S3',
      mimetype: 'text/csv',
      path: 'some-path.csv',
      access: 'public',
    }
  };

  request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        console.log(body);
  });
```